# CSS grid not working for me can anyone provide a solution?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-cont {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 40px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.grid-item-6 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 5;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-cont">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-4">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-5">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-6">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-7">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-8">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-9">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-10">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-11">11</div>
</div>
```

I am currently facing an issue with CSS grid-row;
required output:3 rows 6th element row height twice as other elements
output obtained:3 rows with equal row height

Answer (score 0):

Define a row height

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-cont {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* added */
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 40px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.grid-item-6 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 5;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-cont">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-4">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-5">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-6">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-7">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-8">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-9">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-10">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-11">11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I tried increasing the padding of the middle row which actually worked. :)